# How can I prevent a regex expression to go beyond the end of a string/line

Tags: regex, xcode, swift

Given this string:

```
if let value = json["PropertyID"].int { self.propertyID = value }
```

I have successfully matched and replaced to this one:

```
self.propertyID = representation.valueForKey("PropertyID")?.integerValue
```

**Note:** the entire string changes, except for **propertyID** and **"PropertyID"** that are reused to build the new string

And so, applying this regex expression:

```
// Match
if let value = json\["([^\)]*)"\].int \{ self.([^\)]*) = value \}
// Replace
self.$2 = representation.valueForKey("$1")?.integerValue
```

The result output is this **perfectly formatted string**:

```
self.propertyID = representation.valueForKey("PropertyID")?.integerValue
```

So far so good!
**However,** the text/code file that I'm trying to match and replace, actually looks more like this:

```
if let value = json["PropertyID"].int { self.propertyID = value }
if let value = json["UniqueID"].string { self.propertyUniqueID = value }
if let value = json["TypologyDescription"].string { self.typology = value }
if let value = json["RoomsNumber"].int { self.bedrooms = value }
if let value = json["BathroomsNumber"].int { self.bathrooms = value }
if let value = json["GrossBuiltArea"].decimal { self.grossBuiltArea = value }
if let value = json["TotalLandArea"].decimal { self.totalLandArea = value }
if let value = json["CurrentAskingPrice"].decimal { self.price = value }
if let value = json["CurrencyDescription"].string { self.currency = value }
if let value = json["CountryDescription"].string { self.country = value }
if let value = json["DistrictDescription"].string { self.district = value }
if let value = json["CountyDescription"].string { self.county = value }
if let value = json["ParishDescription"].string { self.parish = value }
if let value = json["Latitude"].decimal { self.latitude = value }
if let value = json["Longitude"].decimal { self.longitude = value }
if let value = json["DefaultPhotoID"].int { self.defaultPhotoID = value }
if let value = json["PropertyStageStatus"].string { self.propertyStageStatusDescription = value }
if let value = json["PropertyStageSubStatus"].string { self.propertyStageSubStatusDescription = value }
```

At this point, the regex expression doesn't seem to care about boundaries. It matches the entire text instead of multiple occurrences (I'm expecting 4 in this example).

I understand why this happens! Just not how to overcome it yet... I need it to begin at **"if"** and end at **"}"** and don't go beyond that line! Giving me the 4 occurrences and not the whole text/code as 1 single occurrence.

I've been trying to understand [boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) but unable to apply them to this context so far.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. This is correct regex

```
json\["([^\]]*)"\]\.int \{ self\.([^}]*) = value \}
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sO6dY8/1)**

**Mistakes in your regex**

i) `.` represent any character. You need to escape `.` as `\.` to match `.` literally

ii) You are using `\["([^\)]*)"\]` but you need to use `["([^]]*)"\]` because you want to match anything except `]` not `)`. You can even use `["([^"]*)"\]`

iii) You are using `([^\)]*)` but you need to use `([^}]*)` or `([^\s]*)` or `([^=]*)`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the regular expression. The regex you used is:

```
if let value = json\["([^\)]*)"\] ......
```

What does that bit on the right actually mean? [Here is a visualisation](https://regexper.com/#json%5C%5B%22(%5B%5E%5C)%5D*)%22%5C%5D).

Why are you looping over "anything but a closing bracket"? *This* is what's causing your match to go across multiple lines.

Instead, what you should be using is "anything but a `"` character", i.e.

```
if let value = json\["([^"]*)"\] ......
```